# How can i change the background color in jQuery.ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to change the background color of tabs in jquery.ui tabs.
Normally it works by default color. 
My code is

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#2"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    </ul>

    <div  id="1">
        <p>MY DATA</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <p>MY DATA 2nd</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
   $('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) { 
        $('#tabs').css('background-color', '#231f20');
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav a
{
   background-color: #231f20;
}
```

Comment: With this solution the tabs are not longer rounded.