# Changing tabs color using jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tabs created using HTML and JQuery UI.

PFB the link.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Mzr5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hiding tab content except first one
    $(".tabContent").not(":first").hide();
    // adding Active class to first selected tab and show
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 

    // Click event on tab
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        // Removing class of Active tab
        $("ul.tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
        // Adding Active class to Clicked tab
        $(this).addClass("active");
        // hiding all the tab contents
        $(".tabContent").hide();       
        // showing the clicked tab's content using fading effect
        $($('a',this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');

        return false;
    });

});
```

**Is it possible to change the color of the tabs?**

Comment: what do you mean by __color of the tabs?__ and yes you can

Comment: jogesh, i mean background color of the tabs..

Comment: of rest tabs or active tab?

Comment: check the answer and fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/2Mzr5/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hiding tab content except first one
    $(".tabContent").not(":first").hide();

    // adding Active class to first selected tab and show
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 

    // Click event on tab
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        // Removing class of Active tab
        $("ul.tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("colorz");

        // Adding Active class to Clicked tab
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("ul.tabs li").not( $(this) ).addClass("colorz");

        // hiding all the tab contents
        $(".tabContent").hide();       

        // showing the clicked tab's content using fading effect
        $($('a',this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: jogesh, thanx for your answer. Also, is it possible to reduce the height of tabs?

Comment: @user755806 i deserve for a credit for it ;), check out this http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/2Mzr5/13/

Comment: Thanks much. Could you please tell me which style u changed?

Comment: @user755806 OH my lol, i think you have to do something with your own. anyway `ul.tabs {height:22px;}`, `ul.tabs li {height:21px;line-height:21px;}` and `ul.tabs li a {font-size:1em;}`. Simple thing is just compare with your old fiddle and this fiddle, take a look on the basic CSS stuff. Wish you for bright future on web developemnt ;) hope now everything is finish, don't forget to mark it solved.

Comment: Jogesh, Thank u so much.it worked..Final question :-), how can i reduce the space between the tabs?

Comment: @user755806 OH man, i told you to take a look on CSS, `ul.tabs li {margin:0 1px -1px 0;}` the second `1px` means margin from right. and the total it starts from: TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT or you can say clockwise..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48017/discussion-between-jogesh-pi-and-user755806)

Answer (score 0):

On `Chrome`, right click and select `Inspect Element`, find the class of the tab, and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing adding active class or any other class that is being set by `jqueryui`, you must change it in jqueryui.css file. You can define additional classes against each color. Removing native classes is not a good idea. You will need them at some point. You can check css file in your browser by pressing `F12` key and in right pane you can see styles. There you will find path of file that generated this style. If this css file is being loaded remotely, you can override your styles by adding `!important` poperty. For example, to change color of `.active` you can do something like following code in your css files.

```
.active{
     background: #FFF !important;
}
```

Comment: Bilal, where can i find it?

Comment: In your fiddle look for `ul.tabs li` in css and change background to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this a duplicate question to this. Please follow this one to get the answer.
[How can i change the background color in jQuery.ui tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478303/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-in-jquery-ui-tabs)

alternatively you can use:

```
CSS:

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav
{
background: red;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel /* just in case you want to change the panel */
{
background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css class:

```
.red-background{
    background-color: red !important; /* important is required to override */
}
```

In your jquery call and add this class as required. For example:

```
$("ul.tabs li").addClass("red-background");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/2Mzr5/14/

You can change the background attribute of

```
ul.tabs li
```

in the css classes